# How often does iCloud sync bookmarks, between iPhone 4 and iPad 2

Tags: icloud, bookmarks

I've just updated an iPhone 4 and an iPad 2 to iOS 5, and turned on iCloud, with syncing of Bookmarks enabled on both. And they are tied to the same Apple ID too.

For both devices, iTunes says "Your bookmarks are being synced with your iPhone over the air from iCloud. Over-the-air settings can be changed on your [device]"

So I expected that if I deleted a Safari bookmark on the iPhone, the change would get reflected in the Safari bookmarks on the iPad.

This update hasn't yet happened, after around 5 minutes.

(But photos do get updated almost instantaneously, I see)

Do I need to do anything special to force bookmark changes to be rolled out to the other device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it may be tied to the **Fetch New Data** setting in **Mail, Contacts, Calendars**.

When I change that setting to **Push**, the bookmarks are sent out straight away.

What I don't understand is why the Photo Stream pushes out changes immediately, even if 'Fetch New Data' is set to 'Every 15 Minutes', but the Bookmarks (which appear to have nothing to do with 'Mail, Contacts, Calendars', are not.

**Later:**

I've just seen the "Advanced" setting in "Fetch New Data". This seems to have a manual override

With **Fetch New Data** set to "15 min", (and Push is Off), and iCloud set to "Push", I expected to have the bookmark pushed out straight away.

But this doesn't happen: I also have to turn the *main* "Fetch New Data" setting to Push, in order to have the bookmarks updated immediately.